# How to skip Virtual Directories in Web Deploy Command line?

Tags: iis, iis-7, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I use web deploy command line batch files to sync Staging and Production servers.

Production server has some virtual directories that are being shared between nodes (on Shared Drive).

I would like to skip virtual directory bindings from  being synced ?

Can anyone help me with a switch that does it efficiently!

I appreciate your help.

EXAMPLE.

- Virtual Directory Images on Development server is binded to a share drive on LOCAL NAS.
- where as on Production it is binded to a shared drive (Different Location).
- when i sync production environment with development the binding of virtual directory Changes to LOCAL NAS.
- I would like to stop virtual directory binding synchronization.

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `-skip` parameters (although, I have never applied them to Virtul Directories as I usually sync specific web apps, not entire web servers). E.g.

```
-skip:objectname='filePath',absolutepath='logs\\.*\\someNameToExclude\.txt'
```

See the [manual on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> ```
> -skip:skipAction=<action>,objectName=<objectName>,keyAttribute=<key>,absolutePath=<absolutePath>,attributes.<attributeName>=<attributeValue>,xPath=<xpathExpression>
> ```
>
> Special Shortcuts
>
> ```
> -skip:ApplicationPool=<applicationPoolName>
> -skip:Directory=<directoryPath>
> -skip:File=<filePath>
> -skip:WebApplication=<webApplicationName>
> -skip:WebSite=<webSitelName>
> ```

Comment: This does not serve purpose. I am trying to stop the bindings from being synced.